# How to setup Kamailio as a simple relay

Tags: sip, kamailio

I have a number of simple SIP endpoints that can be registered on a backend SIP registrars. They can be configured to be registred only on one of the call precessing engines.
I want to use Kamailio to relay REGISTER (and later INVITE) requests to the backend.

So far I have the following config

```
route[REGISTRAR] {
        if (is_method("REGISTER")){
                rewritehost("1.2.3.4");
                xlog("Registering $(fu{uri.user}) with 1.2.3.4\n");
                $var(frst) = "sip:" + $(fu{uri.user}) +"@1.2.3.4";
                $var(scnd) = "sip:" + $(fu{uri.user}) +"@2.3.4.5";
                uac_replace_from("$var(frst)");
                uac_replace_to("$var(frst)");
                if( !t_relay_to_tcp("1.2.3.4","5060") ) {
                        rewritehost("2.3.4.5");
                        uac_replace_from("$var(scnd)");
                        uac_replace_to("$var(scnd)");
                        xlog("Registering $(fu{uri.user}) with 2.3.4.5\n");
                        if( !t_relay_to_tcp("2.3.4.5","5060") ) {
                                sl_reply_error();
                        }
                }
                exit;
        }
   else return;
}
```

This route[REGISTRAR] is called from main SIP request routing. If 1.2.3.4 is UP my test endpoint registers and available for call from other endpoints (though I have to work with INVITE from test endpoint as well). But when 1.2.3.4 is down I get

```
ERROR: <core> [tcp_main.c:4249]: tcpconn_main_timeout(): connect 1.2.3.4:5060 failed (timeout)
```

in the /var/log/syslog. I thought that is t_relay_to_tcp fails I can repeat mangling of From and To headers and relay everything to 2.3.4.5, but this doesn't happen.

It might be because of the asyncronous nature of the transmission - kamailio scripts goes further while relayed tcp session is hanging in some backgroud thread.

How should I edit route[REGISTRAR] to relay to the 2.3.4.5 in case of tcp timeout?

Maybe the whole idea of relaying messages that way is wrong?

*Some forums shows examples of registreing endpoints on kamailio itself, but it doesn't suit me. I believe that kamailio is powerful enough to solve my problem.*

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Kamailio doesn't work this way. So I changed my config like that:

```
route[REGISTRAR] {
        if (is_method("REGISTER")){
                rewritehost("1.2.3.4");
                xlog("Registering $(fu{uri.user}) with 1.2.3.4\n");
                $var(frst) = "sip:" + $(fu{uri.user}) +"@1.2.3.4";
                uac_replace_from("$var(frst)");
                uac_replace_to("$var(frst)");
                t_on_failure("REGISTERBACKUP");         
                t_relay_to_tcp("1.2.3.4","5060");
        }
        else return;

failure_route[REGISTERBACKUP] {
    rewritehost("2.3.4.5");
    xlog("Registering $(fu{uri.user}) with 2.3.4.5\n");
    #Edited to relay to 2.3.4.5
    t_relay_to_tcp("2.3.4.5","5060");
}
```

When 1.2.3.4 is down my endpoint registers on 2.3.4.5. When 1.2.3.4 is up is of course registers on it.